# I want to match exactly 2 times with regex

Tags: java, regex

I have something like this string.

> XXXX^^^141409i1^^^XXXX.

I want to match those  3 `^` in a group and the group exactly 2 times. I wrote this but it doesn't seem to work.

`(?:(\^){3}){2}`

### EDIT

I have to split it and extract the number in the middle. The point is that that group should consist of exactly 3 `^` and exactly 2 times. If the first group has only 1 or 2 `^` it will stop matching. That string is user input and if he inputs more than that string, for example `XXXX^^^141409i1^^^XXXX^^^^XXXX` then it shouldn't match the last group, only the first 2. (Sorry if I'm too ambiguous.)

### EDIT2

The point of the exercise is to split the string and get the number in the middle, I wrote this line but the problem is that it matches every ^^^ and i only want to match 2 times exactly.

```
String[] split = s.split("(\\^){3}");
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to do with the string? What is expected result? A boolean check, true or false? Something like `text.matches(".*\\^{3}.*\\^{3}.*")`? Or, `Pattern.compile("(?<!\\^)\\^{3}[^^]*\\^{3}(?!\\^)").matcher(text).find()`?

Comment: If the should be there exactly 2 times `^(?!(?:.*\^{3}){3}).*\^{3}.*\^{3}.*$` https://regex101.com/r/V3DN2x/1

Comment: I have this kind of string XXXX^^^141409i1^^^XXXX. I have to split it  and extract the number in the middle. The point is that that group should consist of exactly 3 '^' and exactly 2 times. If the first group has only 1 or 2 '^' it will stop matching. that string is an user input, and if he inputs more thant that string like XXXX^^^141409i1^^^XXXX^^^^XXXX it shouldn't match the last group, only the first 2 . (sorry if i'm too ambiguous)

Comment: Perhaps capture the first occurrence in a group `^.*?(?<!\^)\^{3}(\w+)\^{3}(?!\^)` https://regex101.com/r/WKuUwX/1/ Then take the group 1 value and extract the digits.

Comment: Seems you tried matching `^^^^^^` try `(?:[^\^]*\^{3}[^\^]*){2}`

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add clarification and more details. You should not add question details in comments. That way, all the details are concentrated in your question and dispersed over several comments.

Comment: For example https://ideone.com/2m2NvG

Comment: Do you mean you need `String[] split = s.split("(?<!\\^)\\^{3}(?!\\^)");`? Or, if you need to extract a number in between two `^^^`, try `s.replaceFirst("^(?:.*[^^])?\\^{3}(\\w+)\\^{3}(?:[^^].*)?$", "$1")` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/UvZPPx/1))

Comment: Another idea: https://ideone.com/PjQb0p (based on TheFourthBird's solution)

Comment: You wrote (under EDIT2): _The point of the exercise is to split the string and get the number in the middle_ Based on your sample string, what "number" are you hoping to extract?

Comment: I meant the string, sorry. But I figured it out in the end. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood what you want, I hope this will help you:

```
String input = "XXXX^^^141409i1^^^XXXX^^^^XXXX";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?\\^{3}(\\w+)\\^{3}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("The number in the middle: " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
The number in the middle: 141409i1
```

Here you can see how it works: https://regexr.com/51r9e